# How to replace , to . | XSLT

Tags: xslt

Output data:

```
<price>1456,58</price>
```

XSLT

```
    <xsl:element name="price">
            <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
        </xsl:element>
```

I try to replace `,` to `.` to get result:

```
<price>1456.58</price>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code:-

```
<xsl:element name="price">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(//price, ',', '.')"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`translate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) function..

---